# Ms- Access, VBA Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written the following code on click of a button in a Form, which should return current screen size in Ms-Access

```
Option Compare Database

Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long


Private Sub Command0_Enter()


Dim w As Long, h As Long
    w = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' width in points
    h = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' height in points

End Sub
```

I am getting the following error:

> The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting
>   produced the following error: Only comments may appear after End Sub,
>   End Function or end property

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `Declare Function` statement needs to be outside (above) `Private Sub Command0_Enter()`.

Comment: In addition to that, you must use `Private Declare` in a form module, or put it into a public module.

Comment: I did the changes, still same issue

Comment: I'd suggest you check again, as the above example works fine for me once I put `Private Declare` instead of `Declare` for the function